# Extract Data from PDF and populate in Excel using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need bit of advice .............
I'm working on a program in Python, the program would read data from a PDF  and I'm supposed to populate the same information in a excel sheet
Right now I'm using PyPDF 2 to extract the data and I would be using Panda to store the data in a data frame and then that data frame would be populated in to excel sheet
Is my path of action efficient and if there's a better way or a flaw in my plan please let me know about it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show the [code you have so far](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this.

```
import PyPDF2
import openpyxl

pdfFileObj = open('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/TABLES.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pdfReader.numPages

pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
mytext = pageObj.extractText()


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/excel.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'MyPDF'
sheet['A1'] = mytext

wb.save('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/excel.xlsx')
print('DONE!!')
```

See the link below for more details.

http://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Comment: Does not work. Just puts the whole dataset into the first cell of the Excel file instead of rendering it as a table(s)